# Upgrading Spring Boot 1.4.4 to 1.5.4 - NoClassDefFoundError: ServletRegistrationBean

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working with a Java service built with Maven and using the Spring Boot framework. As of right now, my service's pom.xml has the following:

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
```

I'm trying to upgrade to Spring Boot 1.5.4, but I'm getting an error on Application startup (basically, when I run the .JAR file of my project).

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.4.RELEASE)
Application startup failed
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$BeanPostProcessorsRegistrar.registerSyntheticBeanIfMissing(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java:148)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$BeanPostProcessorsRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java:137)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:354)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 59 common frames omitted
```

What I've found by looking around is that the org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean class has been deprecated in between the two Spring Boot versions; instead, the org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean class is used.

However, I'm stuck on what could be possibly using the ServletRegistrationBean class. I do not see any direct references in the pom.xml of my service or in any imports in the Java code. This leads me to believe that it is possibly used in a downstream dependency, but there are so many that it's difficult to know where it could be.

I've tried mvn dependency:tree to see a dependency tree, but it doesn't seem too helpful in narrowing things down. Any further ideas?

Comment: Are you bringing in any other dependencies? In spring boot issue 8186 Stéphane Nicoll states You can't have that issue with "just spring-boot-starter-web".

Comment: Best to list the dependency tree, https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html

Comment: Try adding `<properties>
    <org.springframework.boot>1.4.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.boot>
</properties>` to your pom. However, this will have compatibility issues with your boot app as we are overriding versions. Consider using `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to build successfully, but only after fixing a downstream dependency that was referenced in my service's pom.xml.

It was tough to track down since it was a dependency of a dependency; ultimately, the Maven dependency tree did help me at least figure out where I could narrow down the dependencies imported into my project.

The exact issue was the fact that the dependency in question had an import of org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean; this was deprecated in favor of org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean, as I said in the question.

I simply had to make sure that the import was updated and that the new dependency was used in my project, and the upgrade to Spring 1.5.4 worked.